# count True False, every day for a month and join from 2 table SQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have an attendance table included wfo/wfh records and also have employees table too. I want to count is the employee working from home or office on every date, for every month. I need to join it to employees table too, to count those employees from all cities except 2. Can you guys please help constructed it? Thank you..

```
SELECT b.created_at,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN b.is_wfh = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'WFH',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN b.is_wfh = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'WFO'
FROM attendancetable b
JOIN employeetable a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31'
AND a.office_location NOT LIKE '%D%' AND a.office_location NOT LIKE '%E%'
```

sorry I'm not that good with english. here's the example

employee table

```
name     employee_id   office_location
======================================
Happy         1             A 
Sad           2             B
Angry         3             C
Hungry        4             D
Grumpy        5             E
```

attendance table

```
employee_id   created_at      is_wfh
======================================
     1        2022-01-01       true
     2        2022-01-01       true
     3        2022-01-01       false
     4        2022-01-01       false
     5        2022-01-01       false
     1        2022-01-02       false
     2        2022-01-02       true
     3        2022-01-02       false
     4        2022-01-02       true
    ...           ...          ...
```

expected (count wfh and wfo) result with conditions:
employee from A, B, C only AND date between 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-31

```
created_at      wfh     wfo
============================
2022-01-01       2       1
2022-01-02       1       2
```

I hope my explanation is enough.. thankyou!
...

Sorry I wanna ask more question. If there's time record at created_at field, what should I do to combine all those counting of wfh/wfo?

Comment: What is the actual issue with your query? Can you please send sample data and the tables structures? Basically if i understand your problem,  you would need an outer select and the inner select should group by month and the outer select group by day

Comment: Please post data examples and expected result as well in text format. And your query needs `GROUP BY b.created_at` in the end

Comment: Repeating the same query in your question is not really helpful. Please provide example **data** for each table, and then add the output you would expect for those data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing aggregate function always you need a group by clause.
I replaced not like condition with `e.office_location IN ('A','B','C')` because you only want `employee from A, B, C only` .

Try:

```
SELECT a.created_at,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN is_wfh = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'WFH',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN is_wfh = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'WFO'
FROM attendance a
JOIN employee e ON a.employee_id = e.employee_id
WHERE a.created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31'
AND e.office_location IN ('A','B','C')
group by a.created_at
order by a.created_at asc;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> created_at    WFH WFO
> 2022-01-01     2   1
> 2022-01-02     1   2
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ac3ec9d8b6827e77b806b2180674fa7)

Comment: thankyou so much! I wanna ask if there's time record at created_at field, what should I do to combine all wfh/wfo in one record?